# Reference data n levels up

Tags: mysql

```
Select foo from bar Where
    (Select foo from baz Where
        (Select foo from blah Where foo = foo))
```

How can I make the last `foo` point to the `foo` from n levels up? N levels from top? As I understand it, it will be from the parent query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this using table aliases:

```
Select b.foo
from bar b
Where (Select bz.foo
       from baz bz
       Where (Select bl.foo from blah bl Where bl.foo = b.foo)
     );
```

It is always a good idea to define aliases as abbreviations for tables (so you can look at the alias and be immediately reminded which table it comes from).  And then to use those aliaess for all column references.